# (Sprint Boot) how to use 'IF' of mysql in jpa

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```sql
SELECT *, IF(parent_idx = 0, idx, parent_idx) AS order1
               FROM ida.post ORDER BY order1;
```

I want to sort by using the above sql statement.

Is there a way to use if in jpa?? Or should I do the sorting myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPQL you have `CASE WHEN`. Your example would look like:

```sql
SELECT p, CASE WHEN (parent_idx = 0) THEN idx ELSE parent_idx END AS order1
FROM ida.post AS p 
ORDER BY order1;
```